# What are the options to expose AngularJS frontend on the same server as JAX-RS REST API?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, glassfish, grizzly

[Jersey JAX-RS REST API application](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/snapshot/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype) is pretty much like described here that runs on top of Grizzly container. There is need to map / host content of `src\main\webapp` folder that has AngularJS app that consumes REST API.

At the moment the REST API is bootstrapped in `Main` with help of Grizzly:

```
GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(....);
```

What are the options to run both the REST API and frontend on same server? 
How to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

`GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(....);` returns an instance of `HttpServer`, which is just a generic server preconfigured with a network listener and Jersey http handler.

As such, it handles only REST reuquest (by Jersey http handler), but you may add your own http handlers to handle your web app (html, js, css, ...):

```
HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(....);
server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(....) // add your handler here and map it to URL
```

Have a look at the [Jersey source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-grizzly2-http/2.19/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java#GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer%28java.net.URI%2Corg.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer%2Cboolean%2Corg.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLEngineConfigurator%2Cboolean%29) for more details.

Comment: It might come handy to use this micro http server framework: https://github.com/AdamBien/nano/blob/master/nano/src/main/java/nano/Server.java. You may take Server.java as an example and use `Contexts.create(server, p));` with the server returned by createHttpServer(...).